# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 20.04 with USB while having corrupted 18.04 OS installed without losing files?

Tags: 18.04

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and thought of updating to 18.04.  After updating to 18.04 I came across a lot of problems. While resolving those errors I did something (stuck in deadlock ...unmet dependencies issue) which I haven't been able to fix.

Currently I am able to see grub menu. In boot manager I see two ubuntus: ubuntu and Ubuntu. Choosing them brings back the grub menu.

I was worried I might have lost my files which when I checked with 16.04 USB installation were still there on hard drive.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate more.

Comment: The best action is to backup any file you haven't backup already and install fresh.

Comment: Upgrades sometimes fix problems...but often make the problem worse instead.

Comment: It'll depend on what corruption you're talking about.   If it's package problems, I'd likely *upgrade via re-install* using *Something else*, selecting existing partitions & no-format... It causes system directories to be wiped (package flaws will be gone as packages are erased), new system installed then your prior packages are attempted to be re-installed (works great for Ubuntu repository packages). You'll get an error if any can't be restored (expect it for 3rd party, or python2, Qt4 or anything that's now EOL) but user files are **not** touched which is great for desktops. \

Comment: Note: You didn't say if you're asking about Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, so my last comment assumes Ubuntu Desktop install... the erasure of system directories is more damaging to server applications (which often store .conf) files in system directories thus are lost... thus more work is required to get a server back functional.... Anyway make sure you have backups before either.